# Python Fabric - How to run a command silently and not wait for the output

Tags: fabric

I want to run

```
run("flower -A app")
```

and run that web app in the background without waiting for the output.
I've already seen the dicussions about setting pty=False but it's not helping.
Here are all the possibilities that I've tried:

```
## these methods blocked fabric:
run("flower -A app >& /dev/null < /dev/null &", pty=False)

with quiet():
    run("nohup flower -A app")

run("nohup flower -A app>& /dev/null < /dev/null &"


## fabric waits for the stdout:
run("nohup flower -A app > /dev/null 2>&1")

## fabric is not blocked but the process is not started:
run("nohup flower -A app > /dev/null 2>&1 &")
run("flower -A {} app > /dev/null 2>&1 &")

with quiet():
    run("flower -A app")
```

Does anyone have any other suggestions that I can try?

Comment: I have the same problem, did you resolve it?

Comment: @David I ended up calling paramiko from within my fabric code for this types of commands. You can pass fabric's host and private_key to paramiko. That's not too messy. I hope this helps.

Comment: thanks! I would try paramiko

Answer (score 0):

Did you tried to run it in the background like this - 
run("flower -A app &")

Comment: This won't work as this when disconnected from terminal, bg tasks are killed off. you'll need to nohup this cmd or disown it